# Dynamic function building in Python

Tags: python, function

I need to create a function for an arbitrary number of peaks to pass to a least square fitting routine. For each peak there is an extra term in the function, i.e.

One term with a value at 50 returns a function: `f(p, x) = p[0]*50`

Two terms with values at 50, 60 returns a function: `f(p, x) = p[0]*50 + p[1]*60*x`

Three terms with values at 50, 60, 70 returns: `f(p, x) = p[0]*50 + p[1]*60*x + p[2]*70*x^2`

etc.

A couple of naive attempts are shown below,

```
def foo(vals):
    fn = lambda p, x: 0
    i = 0
    for v in vals:
        fn = lambda p, x : fn(p, x) + p[i] * v * x**i
        i += 1
    return fn
# Causes a recursion error (I think)
```

Second attempt ...

```
def bar(vals):
    terms = []
    i = 0
    for v in vals:
        terms.append(lambda x, p: p[i] * v * x**i)
        i += 1
    def fn(x, p):
        tvals = [t(x, p) for t in terms]
        sum = 0
        for t in terms:
            sum = sum + t(x, p)
        return sum
    return fn
# Generates the wrong values
```

I suspect that this is a problem with referencing, i.e. Python refers to list declarations etc. but this is a little complicated to untangle - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a test case, showing what you're expecting to get (and what you're getting in the second case)?

Comment: Yeah it's a bit hard to guess what you want, especially since the first does just overwrite `fn` alot ...

Comment: Ah, It seems in the second attempt I copied the code when I was trying to debug, it shouldn't return a list, it should return the sum of that list ... Also I explained the desired outcome a little better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def foo(vals):
    def f(p,x):
        result=0
        for i,(av,ap) in enumerate(zip(vals,p)):
            result+=av*ap*(x**i)
        return result
    return f

print(foo([50])([2],3))
# f(p,x)=50*2
# 100
print(foo([50,60])([2,3],4))
# f(p,x)=50*2+60*3*x
# 820
```

Answer (score 1):

Closures don't capture the values of variables in outer scopes at the time of their creation, they really capture these variables. `[lambda: i for i in range(5)]` gives you five functions that all return 4, because they all refer to the same `i` (which is 4 when iteration ends). You can hack around this by using default arguments (which are bind values at function definition time): `[lambda i=i: i for i in range(5)]` works as expected.

Also, use `enumerate`. This, together with making `fn` a lambda, can reduce your code to **just two**, imo equally readable, lines (I'm assuming the second version, the first seems broken in more ways, as indicated in comments):

```
def bar(vals):
    terms = [lambda x, p, i=i, v=v: p[i] * v * x**i for i, v in enumerate(vals)]
    return lambda x, p: sum(term(x, p) for term in terms)
```

Comment: Each of these terms give the right value (although it is the sum of the terms I am after - my bad, see question comments) - I can put this in a for loop to sum them up - as in the question - but is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: @Brendan: Sure, the `sum` built-in.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise there was such a thing in plain Python (I usually use Numpy) - if I could also nominate this as a second answer I would

Answer (score 1):

You can write the whole thing as a function that returns a closure:

```
def make_function(vals):
    def evaluate(x,p):
        return sum(p[i] * v * x**i
                   for i,v in enumerate(vals))
    return evaluate
```

The issue you're running into with the `terms` functions comes up regularly. I wrote a long explanation [about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145893/how-are-closures-implemented-in-python/3145965#3145965) before, hopefully it will be helpful.

Btw, `foo` and `bar` are *syntactic* variables, which means they are used to explain the *syntax*. For implementation problems you should really use good names that mean something in the domain, that often makes the problem much easier to understand.

Comment: Hmm, this returns a generator not a function ... it needs to be a function (in the mathematical sense) for the fitting routine to work

Comment: @Brendan yeah i wrote what you had as 2nd attempt before. As you can see it doesnt take much to transform it to a sum.

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification stores a reference to each `fn` in a default parameter

```
def foo(vals):
    fn = lambda p, x: 0
    i = 0
    for v in vals:
        fn = lambda p, x, f=fn, i=i: f(p, x) + p[i] * v * x**i
        i += 1
    return fn
```

Comment: @Brendan, yeah needs to be closed on `i` too.