# How does a Python closure captures variables of its containing scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

Consider the code below:

```
def foo():
   print('------- entering foo() ---------')

   def internal():
      print('x in internal: {}'.format(x))
      print('id(x) in internal: {}'.format(id(x)))
      print()

   x = 100
   internal()

   global f
   f = internal

   x = 111
   internal()

   print('------- exiting foo() ---------')
   print()


foo()
f()
```

The output of the code is:

```
------- entering foo() ---------
x in internal: 100
id(x) in internal: 4362053072

x in internal: 111
id(x) in internal: 4362053424

------- exiting foo() ---------
x in internal: 111
id(x) in internal: 4362053424
```

The stack frame of the execution of `foo()` should be destroyed once the execution is complete? However, according to the output of the code above, it seems to me that the closure of `internal` referenced by `f` has access to the stack frame of the execution `foo()` that assigned `f`. How can `f` have access to the stack frame of the execution of `foo()` if the stack frame is already destroyed?

Comment: The frame is kept alive, see [this answer in the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3146140/5014455) for a step by step. You can use [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to see what is going on with your code, I believe in Python 3.7 it will recursively disassemble code objects, which is handy.

Comment: Here is a replit: https://repl.it/@juanpa_arrivillaga/StickySkyblueGlitches

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The frame isn't kept alive. It could have been implemented that way, but it wasn't, most likely because it would keep too much alive. Instead, closure variables use an extra level of indirection through closure cell objects, and only the necessary closure cell objects are preserved.

Comment: @user2357112 That makes sense: `f.__closure__` is a tuples of cell objects.  In any case, some object keeps track of the references. Thanks for the correction. A useful link: https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/cell.html . I'm torn on re-opening this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the input. I got some sense of how nonlocal variables behave in Python. However, as user2357112 has pointed out, the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145893/how-are-closures-implemented/3146140#3146140, you alluded to is not entirely correct. Could you reopen this question, and give a correct answer to this question?